# How would I create lines that rotate with increasing distance in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, transform

I've created a version manually, but it has small errors and I want to create an automated one (attached my manual one here):

[image]

I thought it would have something to do with the Rotate option within the Transform > Rotate panel, or maybe in the Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform panel. But nothing lets me increase the space with each copy.

Been trying to figure this out for an hour now.

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Pie Graph... insert the numbers in increasing increments. Apply the numbers.

[image]

The "wedges" will auto-size to be proportional, and all fit, within the area of the circle. Meaning, the total sum of the numbers does **not** need to equal 100% or 360°. Just enter your values and they *should* all fit. *[*see caveat below*]

Ungroup the graph which will break the link to the data. Then alter however is desired.

[image]

Because the link to the data needs to be broken in order to alter the individual wedges, you'll need to redo all of this if the data set requires changing.

---

**Caveat:** If one of the data points is proportionally too small it may be *omitted* from the graph since it wouldn't be *visually* detectable. In short, the data points need to be large enough to be seen.

Example of this.. here I have 8 data points, but the graph only shows 7:

[image]

The first data point is proportionally too small to be seen. If I increase the value of the first data point, then all 8 wedges will show. Merely increasing the first value by 1 makes it visible on the graph:

[image]

If you have a great many data points, starting with a low value and reaching a very high value, this may be an issue with a pie graph. If this is an issue for me, I'll (irrationally) "tweak" the smaller data point so it's visible on the graph. The data point no longer follows the rational progression of the other values, but actually *seeing* it can be more important in many use cases.

---

Answer (score 0):

One idea: Convert linearly growing line lengths to arc lengths with an art brush.

[image]

1. You can use Blending to make easily a set of lines which have linearly growing lengths. Draw only the top and bottom horizontal lines. (see NOTE2)
2. The blend is expanded and ungrouped. A half of the lines are colored to red just for clarity. The lines are moved to a contiguous chain and defined to be an Art Brush.

Art Brush options: [image]

3. The new brush is applied to a circle. The result is expanded (=Object > Expand Appearance) and ungrouped to separate the arc segments. The blue lines are drawn manually from the center of the circle to the arc joints. They snap.

NOTE1: You must have Smart Guides and Snap to Point ON to make everything to snap exactly. No other snaps! The green line was drawn BEFORE applying the brush, because the centerpoint of the circle vanishes as soon as Expand Appearance is applied. Without it you cannot draw the blue lines.

NOTE2: If you need a logarithmic series instead of linear one, do not use blending. Use Object > Transform > Scale > Copy and repeat by pressing Ctrl+D.

Comment: If you make it out of lines the other way around then you can just scale the inner points to 0

Comment: I tried at first to include 90 degrees rotated lines to my brush. The ends did not fit. No idea, why - an error or bug?